# Next auth social signin problem (Amplify hosting)

Tags: next.js, aws-amplify, next-auth

using next js 13.4
amplify hosting, apply cloudfront

/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js

```
const handler = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    ...
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
  ],

  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, account }) {
      if (account) {
        token.accessToken = account.access_token;
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
      return session;
    },
  },
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

When testing google signin locally, it works well, but when testing on the web after amplify hosting, an error occurs.

500 error occurs in /api/auth/provider path

I would like to know the solution, and if not, I would be grateful if you could tell me the reason

If you need more information, please comment and I will give you the information.